# Generating a SAML SP metadata file that works with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Federation authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I am trying to configure a web application using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for Single-SignOn with ADFS.

To configure their ADFS, my client asked me to provide a SAML Service Provider metadata file matching the following format:

[image: Metadata]

In my application, I am setting up authentication in my OWIN pipeline as so:

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()
{
    MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsoAdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
    Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsoWtrealm"]
});
```

I have 2 questions:

- I can generate an X509 certificate to include in the metadata, but how can I add it to my configuration in the web app?
- Where can I get the URLs for all the `AssertionConsumerService` bindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAML2P (P is for protocol) and WS-FED are two completely different protocols. To confuse things, SAML2 tokens (or assertions in SAML2 lingo) can be carried in WS-FED protocol messages.

You won't get any SAML2P functionality out of a WS-FED middleware. You need a SAML2P middleware. The open source Kentor.AuthServices.Owin package contains such a middleware, that will automatically generate the needed metadata and that has been tested with ADFS.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Kentor.AuthServices*